# path to javaldx not found (error on libdbus-glib-1.so.2) but JRE is available

Tags: paths, jre

trying to run 32 bit dbg build LibreOffice on 64 bits Ubuntu...

```
$ LibreOfficeDev_5.3.0.0.alpha0_Linux_x86_archive/program/soffice
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/..archive/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdbus-glib-1-2 is already the newest version (0.106-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

openJDK and Oracle/Sun JRE are available..
Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue with the latest libreoffice on a production machine.

```
LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2)
```

To fix:

```
sudo apt -y install libreoffice-base
```

This will install all the requirements for libreoffice including the java-jre